# Group velocity vector in spherical coordinates

Tags: vectors, mathematics, plasma-physics

I am trying to understand a derivation from the textbook *Radiation Processes in Plasmas* by G. Bekefi (p. 14).

Start with the group velocity vector
$$\mathbf{w}=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \mathbf{k}}=\hat{\textbf{e}}_{x} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k_{x}}+\hat{\textbf{e}}_{y} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k_{y}}+\hat{\textbf{e}}_{z} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k_{z}}.
$$

The propagation vector **k** is of a wave of frequency $\omega$, where both **k** and $\omega$ which have spread (d$\omega, d\textbf{k}$) and can be expressed in spherical coordinates $$(k, \theta, \phi): \omega=\omega(k, \theta, \phi) \text{ or } k=k(\omega, \theta, \phi).$$

I understand that

$w_{k}=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}$, $w_{\theta}=\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta}$, and $w_{\phi}=\frac{1}{k \sin \theta}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi}.$

But the text also says that

$w_{k}=\left ( \frac{\partial k}{\partial \omega} \right )^{-1},$
$w_{\theta}=-\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial \theta}\left ( \frac{\partial k}{\partial \omega} \right )^{-1},$ and $w_{\phi}=-\frac{1}{k \sin \theta}\frac{\partial k}{\partial \phi}\left ( \frac{\partial k}{\partial \omega} \right )^{-1}$

and I don't understand how those expressions are derived. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read the book and I am not expect in this field, but if   $w_{k}=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}=\left(\frac{\partial k}{\partial \omega}\right)^{-1}$, then the other equalities are obvious :

$$w_{\theta}=\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \theta}= \frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}  \frac{\partial k}{\partial \theta}  = \frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial \theta}\left ( \frac{\partial k}{\partial \omega} \right )^{-1}$$

$$w_{\phi}=\frac{1}{k sin \theta}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial \phi} = \frac{1}{k sin \theta}\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}\frac{\partial k}{\partial \phi} = \frac{1}{k sin \theta}\frac{\partial k}{\partial \phi}\left ( \frac{\partial k}{\partial \omega} \right )^{-1}$$

The sign is specific to this field.

Comment: Thanks, I was quite puzzled by the minus sign.